# Typing in UITextView hides navigation bar automatically. How to prevent this?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` which consists of a `UITableView`, `UITextView` and a `UIButton`. The `UITableView` is supposed to display comments of a post, while `UITextView` and `UIButton` is for getting a comment from the user.

The problem is that whenever the user taps on `UITextView`, the keyboard pops up and pushes the UINavigationController out of screen.

What could be the reason and how to prevent this? I tried setting

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = false
```

but it did not seem to work.

Comment: Am anticipating you are Navigation cotroller ? When the keyboard is showing, you are animating the view to going up, right? .. in case the entire view try to animating the table view to up . Are you using Nav Bar only ?

Comment: It is a little hard to tell without more of your code, but did you try setting the keyboard at the first responder and then resigning first responder when the user is done editing UITextField?